# Can I get POIs using Map or Locate SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, point-of-interest

POI: Point of interest(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_interest)

Is there a iOS api which I can use to get a list of POIs near a user location? Here's what I want - the user enters a search term and I already know his latitude and longitude. I want to get an list with the POI details based on the search terms.

So lets say I search for Starbucks at a particular location, I should get all Starbucks within a radius of say 5 miles from where I am.

Can iOS API do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not natively within iOS, but you can use a third party provider, such as YellowPages.com.

http://www.yellowapi.com

Comment: Thanks. I know we can do this with the third party provider such as google place api(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places). I only want to know, Can we do this with iOS SDK. Thanks again.